# Why might SQLite insert be very slow? (Transactions used)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite

I am inserting 8500 lines at a SQLite database. It takes `> 30sec` at a Core 2 Duo.
Its using 70% of CPU during this time, then the problem is the CPU usage.

I am using transaction.

I create the database, tables and inserts on the fly at a temp file. Then I don´t need to worry about corruption, etc.

I just tried to use this, but dont help:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;
```

What more can I do?

If I run the same script at Firefox SQLite Manager Plugin, it runs instantly.

I run the profiler.

All the time is at

```
27seg System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection, String, SQLiteStatement, UInt32, String&)
```

This method calls the three methods

```
12seg System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.UTF8ToString(IntPtr, Int32)
9seg System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToUTF8(String)
4seg System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_prepare_interop(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr&, IntPtr&, Int32&)
```

You asked to show the insert. Here:

```
INSERT INTO [Criterio] ([cd1],[cd2],[cd3],[dc4],[dc5],[dt6],[dc7],[dt8],[dt9],[dt10],[dt11])VALUES('FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-B897A4DE6949',10,20,'',NULL,NULL,'',NULL,julianday('2011-11-25 17:00:00'),NULL,NULL);
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Criterio (
   cd1          integer NOT NULL,
   cd2         text NOT NULL,
   dc3        text NOT NULL,
   cd4    integer NOT NULL,
   dt5           DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   dt6         DATE NULL,
   dt7          DATE NULL,
   dc8   TEXT NULL,
   dt9   datetime NULL,
   dc10            TEXT NULL,
   dt11            datetime NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (cd2 ASC, cd1 ASC)
```

);

C# Code:

```
        scriptSql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ScriptToTest.txt");

        using (DbCommand comando = Banco.GetSqlStringCommand(scriptSql))
        {
            try
            {
                using (TransactionScope transacao = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    Banco.ExecuteNonQuery(comando);
                    transacao.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.ErroBanco(comando, ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you *sure* a single transaction is being used?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I tried with using (TransactionScope transacao = new TransactionScope()) and with BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT inside the Command text.

Comment: I don't know if it's pertinent but check your antivirus, otherwise you can use process explorer to know if there is somethings on your db file to parasite your program

Comment: The *total* time is ~30s or is that when it was terminated? If the total time is >200s, then it's most likely *too many commits*.

Comment: The inserted code is at question now

Comment: No, I mean whole C# code block that performs inserts, including transaction init/commit etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why pst deleted his answer so I'll re-post the same information from it as this appears to be the correct answer.

According to the SQLite FAQ - [INSERT is really slow - I can only do few dozen INSERTs per second](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

> Actually, SQLite will easily do 50,000 or more INSERT statements per second on an average desktop computer. But it will only do a few dozen transactions per second
>
> ...
>
> By default, each INSERT statement is its own transaction. But if you surround multiple INSERT statements with BEGIN...COMMIT then all the inserts are grouped into a single transaction.

So basically you need to group your INSERTs into fewer transactions.

**Update:** So the problem is probably mostly due to the sheer size of the SQL script - SQLite needs to parse the entire script before it can execute, but the parser will be designed to parse small scripts not massive ones!  This is why you are seeing so much time spent in the `SQLite3.Prepare` method.

Instead you should use a parameterised query and insert records in a loop in your C# code, for example if your data was in CSV format in your text file you could use something like this:

```
using (TransactionScope txn = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (DbCommand cmd = Banco.GetSqlStringCommand(sql))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Set the parameters for the command at this point based on the current line
            Banco.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            txn.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fujiy From your code it appears that each INSERT is in its own transaction, however the goal is to have all INSERTs performed in the **same** transaction, unless `scriptSql` contains many insert statements?

Comment: Yes, scriptSql have 4k inserts

Comment: @Fujiy In that case thats probably the cause of your problem - its just tasking ages to parse the command text.  Instead you should use a parameterised query.

Comment: I agreee, since all processor time is wasted at SQLite3.Prepare

Comment: The problem is that my source isn´t CVS or any structure file, it´s a script file. But don´t exists any other solution, I will need to re-write how I create the source

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a parameterized insert? In my experience, transactions will improve speed quite a bit, but parameterized queries have a much bigger impact.

Comment: I will need to refactor much code. I generated the inserts from a select from sql server. The problem is, in firefox it took < 1seg